# Выделить подстроку из строки C#

Tags: c#, .net

Есть форматная строка вида:

```
var formatStr= "STX01{Level:X2}567{Nbyte:X2}ПОДСТРОКА{CRC:D2}".
```

Нужно подсчитать кол-во символов в подстроке и вставить заместо `{Nbyte:X2}`,
Подстрока всегда располагается между `{Nbyte}` и `{CRC}"`.

Как выделить подстроку?

Comment: в substring  вложить indexOf

Comment: Так и делаю но за 1 раз не получается извлечь. за 1 раз извлекаю        "{Nbyte:X2}ПОДСТРОКА{" и только потом 2-ой раз. может с помощью регулярных выражений как - то?

Comment: Потому что вы берете видимо `indexOf("{Nbyte:X2}")`, а надо `indexOf("Nbyte:X2") + "{Nbyte:X2}".Length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение:
{Nbyte:X2}(.*){CRC:D2}

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(
    "STX01{Level:X2}567{Nbyte:X2}ПОДСТРОКА{CRC:D2}", 
    "{Nbyte:X2}(.*){CRC:D2}").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: А можно чтобы вместо STX01{Level:X2}567, те все что до {Nbyte:X2} сделать произвольным. Т.е.  выделять только подстроку отсюда{Nbyte:X2}ПОДСТРОКА{CRC:D2}, а все что кроме игнорировать?

Comment: Не верно выразился в предыдущем Коментарии!!  А можно чтобы "{Nbyte:X2}(.*){CRC:D2}" X2  и D2 были тоже переменными т.е. возможен такой вариант   "{Nbyte}(.*){CRC}" или    "{Nbyte:D3}(.*){CRC:X3}" . Т.е. постоянное только Nbyte и CRC.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, такой вариант для меня более универсален!

```
        string matchString = Regex.Match(
"STX01{Level:X2}567{Nbyte}ПОДСТРОКА{CRC}",
"{Nbyte(.*)}(.*){CRC(.*)}").Groups[2].Value;
```